# How run docker daemon in PyCharm?

Tags: linux, docker, pycharm, linux-mint

I've install Mint os, 20 v. And start set up workspace. Install PyCharm but get error when try to set up environment from docker. Before it I use Ubuntu as my system
[image]
[image]